# Run CakePHP on nginx

Tags: cakephp, nginx, url-rewriting

I try to get an old CakePHP instance running with nginx.

I need to translate this .htaccess rewrite into the syntax of nginx 1.9.3.

This is what I tried so far:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name bz.localhost;

        root /var/www/bz/www/cakesite;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /webroot/app/index.php?$args;
        }
# Another try to get the CakePHP rewrite rules:
#       location / {
#            if (!-e $request_filename) {
#                 rewrite ^/(.+)$ /webroot/$1 last;
#                 break;
#            }
#            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#
#       location /webroot/ {#
#           if (!-e $request_filename) {
#                 rewrite ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 last;
#                 break;
#           }
#       }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

I also tried to set another root:

```
        root /var/www/bz/www/cakesite/webroot/;
```

and

```
        root /var/www/bz/www/cakesite/webroot/app/;
```

None of this worked, I always et the index page in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

first of all please add your website to the vhosts then this config will work for you. If you develop in local server, then you may use subfolder, please change / this to the /subfoldercakephpfolder/ ...

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    rewrite ^/$ /app/webroot/ break;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/webroot/$1 break;

}
location /app/ {
    rewrite ^/$ /webroot/ break;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /webroot/$1 break;
}
location /app/webroot/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
}
```